# python matplotlib f(x^2) plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

Purely out of curiosity I would like to know why the following occurs. I was just doing some basic plot demonstrating an exponential function, and I got a strange result:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(np.arange(0, 1000000, 1)**2)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're hitting the limit of how big of a number can be stored as an integer. On my machine, that array is being generated as an int32 which can at most store the number 2,147,483,647 whose square root is 46340.95 which falls well below the maximum number in your arange.

So numpy is *rolling* the value over back to the minimum number that can be stored by an int, reaching the maximum and then rolling over again. Its increasing in frequency because you're modeling an exponential and the numbers are getting bigger faster.

If you change the dtype to int64, you'll get the full exponential curve you are expecting.